# how can I improve the performance of this slow query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a mysql query which combines data from 3 tables, which I'm calling "first_table", "second_table", and "third_table" as shown below.

This query consistently shows up in the MySQL slow query log, even though all fields referenced in the query are indexed, and the actual amount of data in these tables is not large (< 1000 records, except for "third_table" which has more like 10,000 records).

I'm trying to determine if there is a better way to structure this query to achieve better performance, and what part of this query is likely to be the most likely culprit for causing the slowdown.

Please note that "third_table.placements" is a JSON field type. All "label" fields are varchar(255), "id" fields are primary key integer fields, "sample_img" is an integer, "guid" is a string, "deleted" is an integer, and "timestamp" is a datetime.

```
SELECT DISTINCT first_table.id,
                first_table.label,
                (SELECT guid
                 FROM   second_table
                 WHERE  second_table.id = first_table.sample_img) AS guid,
                Count(third_table.id)                     AS
                related_count,
                Sum(Json_length(third_table.placements))  AS
                placements_count
FROM   first_table
       LEFT JOIN third_table
              ON Json_overlaps(third_table.placements,
                 Cast(first_table.id AS CHAR))
WHERE  first_table.deleted IS NULL
       AND third_table.deleted IS NULL
       AND Unix_timestamp(third_table.timestamp) >= 1647586800
       AND Unix_timestamp(third_table.timestamp) < 1648191600
GROUP  BY first_table.id
ORDER  BY Lower(first_table.label) ASC
LIMIT  0, 1000
```

Comment: The query is malformed. The `LEFT JOIN` gets automatically converted into an `INNER JOIN` behinds the scenes because of the predicate `Unix_timestamp(third_table.timestamp) >= 1647586800`. Please fix the query first, so we can look at the performance of it.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using a correlated subquery for the second table rather than a normal join? Also, if you want people to advise on query performance you really need to include the EXPLAIN PLAN in your question

Comment: After some tinkinering I discovered that the JSON_OVERLAPS is the problem here. As soon as that was removed, the query time went from 10s to about 100ms. Removing the subquery didn't seem to have any impact. Would either of you have any suggestions on how to improve the JSON_OVERLAPS piece?

Comment: json_overlaps returns a boolean so I have no idea what your join is actually doing. I would extract the actual value you need from the json and then join that to first_table.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem is that these are not sargable:

```
    WHERE ... Unix_timestamp(third_table.timestamp) < 1648191600
    ORDER BY  Lower(first_table.label)
```

That is, don't hide a potentially indexed column inside a function call.  Instead:

```
    WHERE ... third_table.timestamp < FROM_UNIXTIME(1648191600)
```

and use a case insensitive `COLLATION` for `first_table.label`.  That is any collation ending in `_ci`.  (Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so I can point that out, and to check the vague "all fields are indexed" -- That usually indicates not knowing the benefits of "composite" indexes.)

`Json_overlaps(...)` is probably also not sargable.  But it gets trickier to fix.  Please explain the structure of the json and the types of `id` and `placements`.

Do you really need 1000 rows in the output?  That is quite large for "pagination".

How big are the tables?  UUIDs/GUIDs are notorious when the tables are too big to be cached in RAM.

It is possibly never useful to have both `SELECT DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`.  Removing the `DISTINCT` *may* speed up the query by avoiding an extra sort.

Do you really want `LEFT JOIN`, not just `JOIN`?  (I don't understand the query enough to make a guess.)

After you have fixed most of those, and if you still need help, I may have a way to get rid of the `GROUP BY` by adding a 'derived' table.  Later.  (Then I may be able to address the "json_overlaps" discussion.)

Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: Thank you! All very helpful comments. I think that I can also replace JSON_CONTAINS with the faster "MEMBER OF"